# Java exceptions can occurs while executing test suite in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Which all type of java exceptions can occurs while executing test suite in selenium?

Comment: They depend on *your* code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking for a base/parent *java-selenium exception*, it is [`WebDriverException`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException).

Answer (score 0):

My answer for above question was the java error while executing selenium test suite are : FileNotFoundException, IOException, ArrayIndexoutOfBoundException, Assertion error, OutOfMemoryError

Please let me know is that correct or any other errors are commonly occurred